# Dado un valor necesito saber hasta que numero se corresponde de una lista de numeros y su índice

Tags: c#

Tengo una lista de números ordenado ascendentemente. Dado un valor necesito saber hasta que numero se corresponde del array y su índice.

```
List<string> myLista = new List<string>(new[] { "2", "9", "17", "25", "35", "42", "70" });
```

Siendo el índice inicial = 0.
Para un valor = 5, El índice seria 1 y el numero 9
Para un valor = 17, El índice seria 2 y el numero 17
Para un valor = 0, El índice seria 0 y el numero 2

Esta es una posible aproximación pero solo me interesa saber índice y valor del ultimo elemento de la lista:

```
myLista.Where(x => Int32.Parse(x) <= Int32.Parse("31")).ToList()
```

Comment: ¿Cual es tu problema?No sabes manejar listas? No sabes como plantearlo?Te da algun error al ejecutarlo?. Comparte con nosotros el codigo que has intentado hasta el momento para tener un punto de partida y poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @wasanga7 quería decir que la numeración del índice empieza por 0. Si el valor dado sobre pasa el ultimo del array por ejemplo 100 entonces el índice seria 6 y valor 70

Comment: @Capt.Teach tengo esta aproximación myLista.Where(x => Int32.Parse(x) <= Int32.Parse("31")).ToList() entonces necesitaría saber que índice tiene el ultimo elemento y que valor.

Comment: Cualquier codigo que tengas que aportar , hazlo en la pregunta (editandola) para que el proximo que lea tu pregunta tenga toda la informacion actualizada. Para obtener el ultimo campo de tu lista filtrada : `var lastItem = list.LastOrDefault();` y para su indice te tendria que valer el tamaño de la lista creo : `var itemSize = list.Count;`

Comment: Ok gracias por la aportación. !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que en la respuesta de Konamiman pides una solución en Linq. Lo único que se me ocurre es lo siguiente:

Podemos usar la sobrecarga de [`Select<TSource,TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Int32,TResult>)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) que incorpora el indice de los elementos, para crear un resultado usando una nueva clase anónima que devuelva tanto el valor como el indice dentro de la lista.

Este es un ejemplo que creo que realiza lo que pides:

```
var listaConIndices=myLista.Select((v, i) => new { Valor = v, Indice = i }).Where(x => Int32.Parse(x.Valor) >= Int32.Parse("0")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Como ves, primero usamos `Select` para crear una clase que tiene las propiedades `Valor`e `Indice`. Posteriormente, buscamos los elementos que sean mayores o iguales al elemento buscado, y nos quedamos con el primero.

Hay que tener en cuenta que si el valor que se le pasa es mayor que el mayor valor de la lista, el resultado en `listaConIndices` sería `null`, asi que deberíamos comprobarlo posteriormente.

Comment: El problema con este enfoque es que si pasas un valor mayor al último de la lista te dará un error. Tendrías que usar `FirstOrDefault` y tomar el último índice/valor de la lista como valor por defecto. La verdad es que creo que este es uno de esos casos en los que LINQ lía más que ayuda (y da lugar a código menos legible).

Comment: @Konamiman efectivamente, no está controlado que pasa si el valor es mayor que el mayor valor de la lista. Pero es sencillo hacerlo, con un simple `if` previo o como bien dices, usando `FirstOrDefault` y comprobando si el resultado es null. Edito para reflejarlo.

Comment: Si el valor es menor al primero de la lista no saldría también nulo ? Tendría que salir el 2

Comment: @Popularfan no. Si el valor es menor actuaria correctamente mostrando el primer elemento. Puedes probarlo si quieres con -300

Comment: @Popularfan aqui lo tienes funcionando: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LrbdoV

Comment: Perfecto !! Gracias !

Answer (score 2):

Si lo he entendido correctamente, necesitas el índice del último número de la lista que es menor o igual al valor que estás comprobando. Este método te lo dará:

```
int IndiceDeUltimolNumeroMenorQue(List<string> valores, int valorAComprobar)
{
    for(int i=0; i<valores.Count; i++)
    {
        if(valorAComprobar <= int.Parse(valores[i]))
            return i;
    }

    return valores.Count - 1;
}
```

Una vez tengas el índice, puedes recuperar el valor fácilmente con `valores[indice]`.

Comment: Perfecto, aunque me gustaría también ver la solución en el caso que use Linq